# controlling an AudioUnit with MIDI keyboard OSX

Tags: macos, audiounit

I'd like to learn if a simple CoreAudio component (of subtype kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput, e.g.), can be parametrically controlled by a MIDI keyboard, let's say MIDI note number be translated into interpollating oscillator frequency? On the other hand, controlling such a parameter by means of a GUI element works like a dream.

I found no single example of such a code on the entire web.
I don't need SinSynth, Sampler, MusicDevice, SoundFonts, Midi files, GM, ADSRs, plug-in level of functionality, etc.

Just need a plain piece of information or hint on how can data from a MIDI packet read by means of a midiReadProc get passed to a audio render callback, much like values of a slider can. With MIDI there seems to be a threading issue, I found no documentation about.

I'd prefer to do it in CoreAudio API, if possible, I'm sure it must be.

On the other hand, using Apple pre-built music instrument devices would lead me into a completely wrong direction.

Thanks in advance,

CA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to controls some of parameters or properties of AudioUnit using MIDI-keyboard. In this case all that you need is take `MIDIPacket`'s `data` field.
What every byte mean you can look [here](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php).
After that, depending on value of needed byte, you need to set property or parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimalistic answer to the question that I've learned and made work meanwhile. It's a matter of making a **midiReadProc** generate values which an **audioRenderProc** can accept as parameters. Please note that this works in stand-alone apps. For writing AU-plug-ins I recommend understanding and using **CoreAudioUtilityClasses**, as provided by Apple.
A simplest example of createMidi in **C**:

```
//these have to be declared somewhere
MIDIClientRef midiclient;
MIDIPortRef   midiin;

void createMIDI (void)
{
//create MIDI input and client - - - - - - - - - - - 
midiclient = 0;

CheckError(MIDIClientCreate(CFSTR("MIDI_Client"), 
                            NULL, 
                            /*midiClientNotifyRefCon*/NULL, 
                            &midiclient), 
            "MIDI Client Create Error\n");

CheckError(MIDIInputPortCreate(midiclient, 
                                CFSTR("MIDI_Input"), 
                                midiReadProc, 
                                NULL, 
                                &midiin),
            "MIDI Port Create Error\n");

//connect MIDI - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -         
ItemCount mSrcs = MIDIGetNumberOfSources();
printf("MIDI Sources: %ld\n", (long)mSrcs);
ItemCount iSrc;

for (iSrc=0; iSrc<mSrcs; iSrc++) {
    MIDIEndpointRef src = MIDIGetSource(iSrc);
    MIDIPortConnectSource(midiin, src, NULL);
    } 
}
```

*CheckError( )* is a generic utility function modeled after *"Learning Core Audio"*, by C.Adamson & K.Avila, ISBN 0-321-63684-8...

...and a plain-C **midiReadProc** template. Please note that many manufacturers of MIDI hardware don't implement the standardized noteOff event, but rather a "hacked" version consisting of a zero-velocity-noteOn, due to alleged improving MIDI-latency issues, but they hardly document it. So, one has to check against both scenarios:

```
void midiReadProc(const MIDIPacketList *packetList, 
              void* readProcRefCon, 
              void* srcConnRefCon)
{
Byte note;
Byte velocity;
MIDIPacket *packet = (MIDIPacket*)packetList->packet;
int count = packetList->numPackets;

for (int k=0; k < count; k++) {
    Byte midiStatus  = packet->data[0];
    Byte midiChannel = midiStatus & 0x0F;
    Byte midiCommand = midiStatus >> 4;

    if ((midiCommand == 0x08)||(midiCommand == 0x09)){        
        if(midiCommand == 0x09){            
            note     = packet->data[1] & 0x7F; 
            velocity = packet->data[2] & 0x7F;

            if (velocity == 0x0){ //"hacked" note-off                
                 ; //do something                                     
            }else{//note on                                                  
                ; //do something                     
            }
        }            
        if(midiCommand == 0x08){ //proper note-off                                   
        ;//do something               
        }
    }else{
    ;//do something else
    }
packet = MIDIPacketNext(packet);    
}//end for (k = 0; ...;...)
}
```

Everything else is a matter of common good programing practice.